# generating different distinct permutation of fixed length(L)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am writing a program to generate different permutation of an array with fixed length of 3.
The main problem I am facing is that it always generate dublicate permutation, How can i fix it without using Java set<>.

```
public class generatingCombination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="ABCDEF";
            printArray(s,0,new char[3], new boolean[s.length()]);

    }

    static void printArray(String s,int x,char []arr, boolean [] used){
        if(x==3){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for( int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if(used[i]) continue;

                arr[x]=s.charAt(i);
                used[i]=true;
                printArray(s, x+1, arr,used);
                used[i]=false;
                printArray(s, x+1, arr,used);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting duplicates because you're doing the recursive call twice. Why are you doing that? What is the point of the `used` array, if you call self without setting value (second recursive call)?

Comment: @YS. - Please provide an example to the output you expect

Comment: The second printArray call will just print out the same the first one does.

Comment: There are some really nice non-recursive permutation algorithms out there that naturally and easily avoid generating duplicates. You might want to investigate C++'s `std::next_permutation` algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in permutations of length 3, then why not just:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "ABCDEF";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
                if (k == i || k == j) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new char[] { s.charAt(i), s.charAt(j), s.charAt(k)}));
            }
        }
    }
}
```